# Restrict column to have the height of another column

Tags: html, css

I want a blue column to have exactly the same height of the white column, that is if content inside the blue column exceeds the height of white column then the blue column will have a scroll. The white column has dynamic content.

Here is what I currently have:
[image]

Here is what I want to achieve:
[image]

```css
.vertical-center > .container {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
}
.card-container.card {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 25px 25px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.card {
  margin: 0;
}
.release-notes {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0082CA;
  overflow: auto;
}
.release-notes > ul {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="card card-container">
        <ul>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-container release-notes text-left">
        <div class="text-uppercase"></div>
        <ul>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi - 2 questions: Will the height of column 1 be dynamic? Are you opposed to using jQuery/JavaScript to solve this if the first column *is* dynamically sized?

Comment: Is it fine to use max-height and remove flex?? like this : https://jsfiddle.net/stv7v2a1/1/

Comment: @Frits, the white column has dynamic content.

Comment: @summerbabe there have been a few answers added here - have any of them helped at all?

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is run a little bit of jQuery to find the height of the `ul` on the left and set the height of the `ul` on the right to the same value.

```
var new_height = jQuery('.card-container.left ul').height();
jQuery('.card-container.release-notes ul').height(new_height);
```

Then you need to set the ul on the right to have `overflow-x:scroll;`

see the edited fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/stv7v2a1/3/

*--- Edit ---*

Please note that I had to add a class to the `ul` on the left to help differentiate it in my jQuery and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure css solution. You will have to create two divs floating, and wrap them in a container. Then you'll have to use a css hack.

Add a huge negative bottom padding, and a positive margin of the same amount. For example:

```
padding-bottom: -500em;
margin-bottom: 500em;
```

This will make your two floating divs an equal height. The rest is simple, by using `min-height` and/or `max-height`

Here is a jsfiddle I quickly made: https://jsfiddle.net/24k3285q/1/

Comment: The problem here is that the divs you set were given the same min and max height. Once you remove that (which in the given scenario is likely as the left div will dynamically change height) the effect is lost - see edited fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/24k3285q/2/

Answer (score 0):

#### Using jQuery

Check here  https://jsfiddle.net/stv7v2a1/4/

**jQuery code used is**

```
$(function(){
  var ht= $('.content').outerHeight();
  $('.release-notes').css({"height":ht});
});
```

---

Given a new class name `content` to the small left `div //for getting its height`

 Added `overflow-y:scroll;` to `release-notes` 
ALso added `align-items:flex-start` to `wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load JQuery you can use plain JavaScript. All you need is a couple of ids and a script tag. Additionally, I would add `overflow: auto` to `.card-container.card` if you want the left list to scroll when longer.

```js
window.onload = function(){
        var leftHeight = document.getElementById('leftlist').offsetHeight;
        var rightHeight = document.getElementById('rightlist').offsetHeight;
        var lowestHeight;

        if (leftHeight < rightHeight) 
          { lowestHeight = leftHeight; } 
        else 
          { lowestHeight = rightHeight; }

        document.getElementById('leftlist').style.height = lowestHeight + 'px';
        document.getElementById('rightlist').style.height = lowestHeight + 'px';
    }
```

```css
.vertical-center > .container {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
}
.card-container.card {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 25px 25px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.card {
  margin: 0;
}
.release-notes {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0082CA;
  overflow: auto;
}
.release-notes > ul {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="card card-container">
        <ul id="leftlist">
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-container release-notes text-left">
        <div class="text-uppercase"></div>
        <ul id="rightlist">
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```